Starting github for exploring projects
I am relatively new in programming and I would like to start collaborating with other new programmers in github (html, css, and python) however all the projects I could find are much higher and harder than my level that I don't understand even wht they are about. Is there a specific place in github for beginner projects? If yes, how can I find it?
Thanks
I looked several times in github website and I couldn't find. I have a github account and several repositories on my current projects.

The stack exchange police are going to close this question.

https://goodfirstissue.dev is aimed at people starting out with open source contributions, maybe worth a look?
